# Dudas con retrofit

Tags: android-studio, rest, retrofit

Tengo que consumir un servicio rest que me han dado pero me pide usuario y contraseña y no se como ingresarlo en la peticion.

Probé con retrofit2 a conectarme y mostrar unos datos en un listview y no tengo problemas,pero el servivio rest que me han dado para mostrarlo luego en un listWiew me pide usuario y contraseña(Los tengo) pero no se como pasarselo
a la aplicacion.

Se me cuelga cuando hace la peticion sin darme opcion a meterle el usuario y contraseña,debo configurarlo en la app?
Debo usar algun servicio?

El servicio rest me dice esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que cuando incovo el get para coger los datos del servicio rest la aplicacion se me cuelga y no se porque
quizas deba pasarle el usuario y contraseña pero no se como.

El formato del Json que me da el servicio rest es este:

{"result":[[[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1],[12,"01",2,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo (activaci\u00F3n)",0,0],[12,"01",3,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo (desactivaci\u00F3n)",0,1]]]}

El mainActivity es este

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.lista.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list;
ArrayList<String> titles  = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    list = findViewById(R.id.list);

    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    getPosts();
}

private void getPosts() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
    Call<List<Post>> call = postService.getPost();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> 
        response) {
            if(response == null)
            {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Response is null");
            }else
            {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Response has contents");
            }


            for (Post post : response.body()) {
                titles.add(post.getTitle());
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", String.valueOf(titles.add(t.getMessage())));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Y el postService de esta manera

```
 import java.util.List;

 import retrofit2.Call;
 import retrofit2.http.GET;
 import retrofit2.http.Header;

 public interface PostService {

 String API_ROUTE =" /posts";

 @GET(API_ROUTE)
 Call< List<Post> > getPost();

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tipo de autenticación que solicita el servidor es Basic Auth. Se deben enviar las credenciales en la cabecera mediante Authorization. Las credenciales deben estar separadas usuario y clave por el caracter ":". Ejemplo: miusuario:miclave. Adicionalmente deben ser codificadas a base64.

Un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

En PostService:

```
Call< List<Post> > getPost(@Header("Authorization") String credencialesEnBase64);
```

En MainActivity:

```
String credenciales = usuario + ":" + clave;
String credencialesEnBase64 = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credenciales.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Call<List<Post>> call = postService.getPost(credencialesEnBase64);
```